# Participating on the kernel mailing list

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, email

I know this questions is a bit edgy regarding the rules. I will ask it regardless for this is the community that might benefit most from it, and the Stack Exchange interface is much more suited for newcomers.

---

- How to subscribe to the mailing list of the Linux kernel or a specific kernel subsystem?
- How to post to the mailing list?
- What is the proper way to reply to someone who replied to my post?
- Are there specific email clients that can cause problems with interacting with the mailing list?

Comment: It would be great if there would be any alternate frontend for this. I can't navigate through this.

Answer (score 8):

The official documentation is [here](http://vger.kernel.org/majordomo-info.html). I'm starting this as a community wiki with the answers that I know.

At the time of this writing sending a test mail from gmail to *autoanswer@vger.kernel.org* results in errors:

```
554 5.0.0 Hi [209.85.218.48], unresolvable address: <autoanswer@vger.kernel.org>; nosuchuser; autoanswer@vger.kernel.org
```

---

> How to subscribe to the mailing list of the linux kernel or a specific
>   kernel subsystem?

Chose the subsystem you'd like to subscribe to from [here](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html). This example will chose [linux-bluetooth](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-bluetooth).

The subscription email will need to be sent in **plain text**. Be sure to check that first :

- Gmail web client -> there is a Plain text mode you can set

The second part is to generate the content of the mail.

To:

`majordomo@vger.kernel.org`

Email body:

`subscribe linux-bluetooth`

Notice that the **subject** is empty and that is how it should be.

If that was successfully received, the server will respond with a message welcoming you to the subsystem mailing list.

---

> How to post to the mailing list?

To post to the mailing list one subscribed to above use the following:

To:

`linux-bluetooth@vger.kernel.org`

Subject:

`Your arbitrary subject`

Email body:

`Your arbitrary plain text body`

The status with Gmail web client at the moment is that you don't receive your own posts from the mailing list, but they do end sent to the all the other subscribers. Don't know a fix for that atm.

Comment: I think you have to confirm first.

Comment: @schaiba These are the steps I did which got me to subscribe successfully and receive posts that others send to the list. Wasn't yet successful in seeing my own posts in the list, or responding to others.

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer You say `The status with Gmail web client at the moment is that you don't receive your own posts from the mailing list`. Does that mean that if I connected to Gmail with Thunderbird or Oitlook, then I *would* receive my own posts?

Answer (score 0):

This has changed.

You now need to visit [this link](https://subspace.kernel.org/vger.kernel.org.html) and click on the sub button for the channel you wish to join.

The subject and body can be blank.